# How to send data from django template to view function via request?

Tags: django, python-3.x, request, jinja2

Basically what I want to do is that whenever user hits "view" button in below code then I send a post/get request and send "sel" as data to a view function because I have to use "sel" in view function. How to do this through forms or ajax request or something else ?

**search.html**

```
 {% for sel in selections %}
               <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                  <img src="../static/listhome/media/images/house2.jpg" width="100%" height="225" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" ><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/></svg>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>Price: </h3>
                  <p> {{sel.address}}<br>
                    Bedrooms: <br>
                    Baths: <br>
                    Square Feet: {{sel.approximate_square_footage}}
                     </p>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                      <div class="btn-group">
## THIS IS BUTTON TO BE USE TO SEND DATA
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      </div>
                      <small class="text-muted">Days listed:  </small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

'Selections' is a list containing some elements from my database. It is the filtered result of my database passed to this template earlier through the following code:

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
    value = request.POST.get('searchvalue')
    selections = Listing.objects.filter(address__contains=value)
    context={
        'selections':selections,
         'value':value,
    }
    return render(request, 'search.html',context)
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having with this approach?

Comment: which method to use to send request should I use forms ?

Comment: Well, it doesn't sound like you shouldn't be using a POST for this. POST is usually used for submitting data to be saved whereas you want to have a search view which would usually be a GET

Comment: I want to know how to send data through this should I use forms or ajax request or something else?

Comment: Not sure what you trying, but I think you can use forms.

Comment: If I use forms then in view function how can I access 'sel' ? @Zoro-Zen

Comment: You might do well to avoid re-inventing the wheel and use django-filters instead. https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: okay i will see @nigel222